# Listing iterations inside a while loop

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, iteration

I wrote a code for bisection method root approximation. However, I wanted to know the value of the root every iteration. I tried using the Union function to save each iterated value in a set but it saves the numbers in increasing order.

I am reading on NestWhileList but I am new to Mathematica and I still do not understand it much. Is there a way to use it?

```
f[x_] := x - E^(-1.2*x);
a = 0.5; b = 1;(*a<b*)
c = 0;
\[Epsilon] = 0.001; (*error*)
iter = 0; 
cList = {};


If[f[a]*f[b] > 0, 
 Print["Conditions of Bisection Method are not met. Disregard \
solution below."], "See solution below"]

While[Abs[b - a]/2 > \[Epsilon],
  
  c = (a + b)/2;
  iter = iter + 1; (*number of iterations*)
  cList = cList \[Union] {c};
  
  f[a];(*left-hand side*)
  f[b];(*right-hand side*)
  f[c];(*mid-point*)
  
  If[f[a]*f[c] < 0, b = c, a = c];
  ];

N[c] (*root*)
iter(*number of iterations*)
cList (*iterated roots*)
```

Comment: what is `f` ?? not defined anywhere. You say `If[f[a]*f[b] > 0` but there is no `f` to be seen before that.

Comment: if you want to save things while running in a loop, and you do not know before hand how large the number of items you want to save is, then the standard way is to use `Sow` and `Reap` but can't show you how, since your code does not run and missing definitions.

Comment: @Nasser thanks for your response. I have included a sample function f for this problem

Comment: You can change `cList = cList \[Union] {c};` to `cList = Append[cList, c];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to collect the values of `c` in cList?

Just replace your loop with

```
cList=First@Last@Reap@While[Abs[b-a]/2>ϵ,
      c=(a+b)/2;
      iter=iter+1;(*number of iterations*)
      Sow[c];
      If[f[a]*f[c]<0,b=c,a=c]
];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Lookup help on `Sow` and `Reap`

Btw, `iter=iter+1` can be written as `iter++` in Mathematica.

Comment: This is it! Thank you very much for your help and advices :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function and test:

```
f = x |-> x - E^(-1.2*x);  (* head is Function *)
test[{a_Real, b_Real}] := Abs[b - a]/2 > 0.001
```

Your iterative step, used with `NestWhileList` (as requested):

```
step[f_Function, {a_Real, b_Real}] /; a < b :=
 With[{c = (a + b)/2.}, If[f[a]*f[c] < 0, {a, c}, {c, b}]]
Mean /@ Most@NestWhileList[step[f, #] &, {0.5, 1.}, test]
```

A closely related alternative, using `Sow`:

```
sowStep[f_Function, {a_Real, b_Real}] /; a < b :=
 With[{c = (a + b)/2.}, Sow[c]; If[f[a]*f[c] < 0, {a, c}, {c, b}]]
First@Last@Reap@NestWhile[sowStep[f, #] &, {0.5, 1.}, test]
```

The latter has a bit less computational redundancy, although that really does not matter here.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`NestWhileList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html)

```
bm[f_, {a_, b_}] := 
 With[{c = (a + b)/2}, If[f[a] f[c] < 0, {a, c}, {c, b}]]
w[f_, a_, b_, e_] := 
 Mean /@ NestWhileList[bm[f, ##] &, {a, b}, 
   Abs[#[[2]] - #[[1]]]/2 > e &]
```

Examples

1.

```
f[x_] := x - E^(-1.2*x);
rt = x /. FindRoot[f[x], {x, 1}]
ans = w[f, 0.5, 1, 0.0001];
ListPlot[ans, GridLines -> {None, {rt}}]
```

[image]

2. functions $x^2-2$, $\sin (x)$, $\cos (x)$

   ```
    ListPlot[w[#^2 - 2 &, 0., 3, 0.0001], GridLines -> {None, {Sqrt[2]}}]
    ListPlot[w[Sin, 2, 4, 0.0001], GridLines -> {None, {Pi}}]
    ListPlot[w[Cos, 1, 2, 0.0001], GridLines -> {None, {Pi/2}}]
   ```

[image]

[image]

[image]